# Filter/search table html on visible elements

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying filtered the contents of a table.
It's ok and working.

But, I have elements with 'display:none' that are hidden on screen and when I'm filter they appear too.

Bellow, I put example the code that I'm working.
How can I filter just visible elements on screen?

Here is the code:

```js
((document => {
    const LightTableFilter = ((Arr => {
  let _input;
  function _onInputEvent(e) {
   _input = e.target;
   const tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
   Arr.forEach.call(tables, table => {
    Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, tbody => {
     Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
    });
   });
  }

  function _filter(row) {
            const text = row.textContent.toLowerCase();
            const val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
            row.style.display = !text.includes(val) ? 'none' : 'table-row';
        }

  return {
   init() {
    const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
    Arr.forEach.call(inputs, input => {
     input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
    });
   }
  };
 }))(Array.prototype);
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
   LightTableFilter.init();
  }
 });
}))(document);
```

```html
<section class="container">
 <h2>es6 Javascript Table Filter</h2>
 <input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Filter">
 <table class="order-table table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
    <td>0123456789</td>
    <td>99</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Jane Vanda</td>
    <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
    <td>9876543210</td>
    <td>349</td>
   </tr>
      <tr style="display: none">
    <td>!@#!@#!qawsed</td>
    <td>ewewewewew@batman.com</td>
    <td>6754328901</td>
    <td>199</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function _filter(row) {
      //if (row.style.display === 'none') return; // optional
      const text = row.textContent.toLowerCase();
      const val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
      !text.includes(val) ? row.classList.add('hidden') : row.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
```

css

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```